# How to disable neurons in the latent space of a pre-trained autoencoder?

Tags: keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I have a question wrt my Neural Network (an autoencoder, more specifically).

I have created a sequential Neural Network to analyse the properties of turbulent flows.

I want to explore the effects of switching on/off neurons in the latent space (the layer where the maximum compression information occurs). I.e. I want to take, say, an NN with 2 hidden layers in the Encoder, 2 hidden layers in the Decoder (with 300 neurons in each one) and 8 neurons in the Latent Space. I want to train the NN on this given architecture and save my weights and biases.

After that, I want to be able to run my NN with a different number of n_modes (see below), let's say 1 or 2. I.e. I still want to use all the weights and biases in the previous layers from the trained model, but I want to disable, for instance, 2 neurons in the latent space (latent_input) in this case. Can I do it? I do not want to train the model on a different number of latent neurons if that makes sense. I just need to throw away a couple of them from the model when I actually predict my outputs given a new data set.

Here is how I run the code. Note that I trained the model already and only load the weights and biases using the load_weights command.

```
def tanh(x):
    return tf.nn.tanh(x)

# ------------------------
# Load or compile model
# ------------------------



n_modes = 4 # this is what I need to change
n_hidden = 300
n_hidden_2 = 300
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(training_features, training_features, test_size=split,
                                                    random_state=1)
# ------------------------
# MODEL
# ------------------------
## Encoder
input_img = ks.Input(shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2], X.shape[3]))
x1 = ks.Reshape([X.shape[1] * X.shape[2] * X.shape[3]])(input_img)
x2 = ks.Dense(n_hidden, use_bias=True, activation=tanh)(x1)
x3 = ks.Dense(n_hidden_2, use_bias=True, activation=tanh)(x2)
encoded = ks.Dense(n_modes, use_bias=True, activation=None)(x3)
## Decoder 
latent_inputs = ks.Input(shape=(n_modes))
y3 = ks.Dense(n_hidden_2, use_bias=True, activation=tanh)(latent_inputs)
y4 = ks.Dense(n_hidden, use_bias=True, activation=tanh)(y3)
y5 = ks.Dense(X.shape[1] * X.shape[2] * X.shape[3], use_bias=True, activation=None)(y4)
decoded = ks.Reshape([X.shape[1], X.shape[2], X.shape[3]])(y5)
ENC = tf.keras.models.Model(input_img, encoded)
DEC = tf.keras.models.Model(latent_inputs, decoded)
autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Model(input_img, DEC(ENC(input_img)))

lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
learning_rate,

decay_steps=2000,
decay_rate=0.2,
staircase=False)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
autoencoder.load_weights('axisymmetric/models/{}MODES_{}HIDDEN_{}HIDDEN_tanh_all_data'.format(n_modes,n_hidden,n_hidden_2))
#PREDICTIONS

P = autoencoder.predict(training_features, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None, callbacks=None)
```

I appreciate your help! Thanks to all of you in advance :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "disable"? If you understand neural networks, it's pretty obvious that you can simulate some types of "disabling" by setting either the corresponding columns in the preceding matrix or the corresponding rows in the following matrix to zero. The chief difference is in the bias terms of the disabled neurons.

Comment: you're thinking op dropout...

Comment: Hi @MSalters, thank you for your prompt response and your feedback. I agree that we can set the specific weights and biases terms to zero. This would work. How would you approach doing this task? Would you manually reassign zeros to a given row/column, or is there a smarter/quicker way? Thanks